# Dynamics GP 2010 Awful Report Performance

Tags: sql-server, dynamics-crm

We are running Dynamics GP 2010 on 2 load balanced citrix servers.  For the past 3 weeks we have had severe performance hits when users are running Fixed Assets reporting.
The database is large in size, but when I run the reports locally on the SQL server, they run great.  The SQL server seems to be performing adequately even when users are seeing slow performance.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Just because your DB seems un-stressed, it does not mean that it is fine. It could contain other bottlenecks.  Typically, if a DB server is not maxing-out its CPUs occasionally, it means there is a much bigger problem.

Standard process for troubleshooting performance problems on a data driven app go like this:

1. Tune DB indexes.  The Tuning Wizard in SSMS is a great starting point.  If you haven't tried this yet, it is a great starting point.
2. Check resource utilization: CPU, RAM. If your CPU is maxed-out, then consider adding/upgrading CPU or optimize code or split your tiers. If your RAM is maxed-out, then consider adding RAM or split your tiers.
3. Check HDD usage: if your queue length goes above 1 very often (more than once per 10 seconds), upgrade disk bandwidth or scale-out your disk (RAID, multiple MDF/LDFs, DB partitioning).
4. Check network bandwidth
5. Check for problems on your app (Dynamics) server

Comment: Thanks @tgolisch, I think I am onto something. we have some shared report dictionaries that were moved to a new share location recently.  I am not sure yet of how the files system is setup on that share versus the other, but this seems a promising lead.  I can run the reports locally on the DB server in seconds, but it takes minutes on the app servers.  I am not so certain the DB is the issue (yet).

Answer (score 0):

Shared report dictionaries are the bane of reporting in GP.  they do tend to slow things down.  also, modifying reports becomes impossible as somebody has it open all the time.
use local report dictionaries and have a system to keep them synced with a "master" reports.dic